# Stimulsoft - How to render report in asp.net core and show it in angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, stimulsoft

[Stimulsoft report:](https://www.stimulsoft.com/en/documentation/online/programming-manual/index.html)

How can I render the report with its variables and parameters in asp.net core and show it in angular?

Angular:

```
viewer: any = new Stimulsoft.Viewer.StiViewer(null, 'StiViewer', false);
report: any = new Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport();

this.report.load("the report get from my api"); // ???

this.viewer.report = this.report;
this.viewer.renderHtml('viewer');
```

Asp.net core:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetReport()
{
    StiReport report = new StiReport();
    report.Load(@"D:\myreport.mrt"); // for example load it from local

    // set parameters and variables here.it's ok

    // this return does not prepare report for showing in angular.It uses for view of action
    return StiNetCoreViewer.GetReportResult(this, report);
}
```

How do I prepare report in this method for showing correctly in angular?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Asp.net core:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetReport()
{
    StiReport report = new StiReport();
    report.Load(@"D:\myreport.mrt");

    // set parameters and variables here.it's ok

    // render the report
    report.Render(false);


    return report.SaveDocumentJsonToString();
   // OR return report.SaveDocumentToString();
}
```

So we use the result of GetReport method into component

Angular component:

```
this.report.load("result of GetReport method");
```

Comment: please add to github

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to build the same example:
https://www.stimulsoft.com/en/documentation/online/programming-manual/reports_js_binding_data.htm.

**Update:**
I did something like this before, what I go to is to let the client open a popup window requesting a specific MVC action that will generate the report.
Another idea is to generate the PDF and use a PDF viewer on the client to show what you already generated.

Comment: Hi. thanks for your answer.
most of example of documentation is, when we have data and report together but my report has connectionstring and params, then it must rendered on server and send the result to client for showing.

Comment: I have done it before.after run my app, a request will be sent to a api and the report will be rendered(the code in my question). but I don't know it's true or not, and if it's true how I show the result in viewer(angular code in my question).