# Show Stimulsoft reporting in Angular by Asp.net Core

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, stimulsoft

I have a Webservice In Asp.net core for generate reporting and call this in Angular app for show reporting but angular doesn't show reporting, just show blank page

What's the problem? How can I solve It?

Asp.net Core WebService :

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ShowPrint(int? id)
{                           
    var res = await _inquiryService.GetStudents(id);
    var result = res.Select(x => new InquiryValueViewModelsPrint()
    {
        SupplierContractorName = x.SupplierContractorName,
        SumTotalPrice = x.SumTotalPrice
    }).ToList();

    var report = new StiReport();
    report.Load(StiNetCoreHelper.MapPath(this, "Reports/inquiry.mrt"));

    report.RegBusinessObject("InquiryObj", result);

    return StiNetCoreViewer.GetReportResult(this, report);
}
```

Angular function :

```
viewer: any;
options: any;
report: any = new Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport();
constructor(...

print(item: InquiryViewModel) {
    this.apiService.showPrint(item.id)
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log( data)
        this.options = new Stimulsoft.Viewer.StiViewerOptions();
        this.viewer = new Stimulsoft.Viewer.StiViewer(this.options, 'StiViewer', false);

        this.report.load(data);

        this.viewer.report = this.report;
        this.viewer.renderHtml('viewer');
      });
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <h2>Stimulsoft Viewer</h2>
    <div id="viewer"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: If you look in the network tab of the debugger do you see the data?  or what does a log of `data` print

Comment: no show error in console browser

Comment: Ok but do you see the request and the actual response with data?

Comment: @jcuypers yes has data.  add `console.log( data)` in web service

Comment: I'm not sure if this satisfies your needs but i have found another link to render in asp and display in angular:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54087229/stimulsoft-how-to-render-report-in-asp-net-core-and-show-it-in-angular.  I'm not sure what is wrong in your case. I dont know the software

Comment: @jcuypers I had read this but did not show reporting

Answer (score -1):

I think it's better that way In Angular.

```
    declare var Stimulsoft: any;
    let viewer = new Stimulsoft.Viewer.StiViewer(null, 'StiViewer', false);
    var report = new Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport();
    report.loadFile('./assets/reports/***.mrt');
    var ds ={ "Report": [
      { "NameField": ""},
      { "NameField": "" }
    ]};
 
    ds.FieldSport=data;
    report.regData("...", "...", ds);
    viewer.report = report;
    viewer.renderHtml("viewerContent");
```

Comment: can you please give a brief summary describing your suggestion so other users don't have to compare every character of code to figure out _what_ is better this way?

Comment: 1:In Method print cannot pass data to stimul 2:unknown file report stimullsoft